# cannot read properties undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

Hi I am trying to change the style inside of an external .css file. You can compile this only on a localhost or a online server. Please help. Thank you!

It keep saying "cannot read properties undefined"

and the external style.css only contains

```
body{}
```

and it keeps giving me an error. What I am doing it wrong?

this is what I am working at:

```js
function setStyleRule(type, attrs) {
  var sheetName = "style";
  var sheets = document.styleSheets,
    stylesheet = sheets[(sheets.length - 1)];

  for (var i in document.styleSheets) {
    if (sheets[i].href && sheets[i].href.indexOf(sheetName + ".css") > -1) {
      stylesheet = sheets[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  var thisCSS = stylesheet;

  //console.log(thisCSS);

  var ruleSearch = thisCSS.cssRules ? thisCSS.cssRules : thisCSS.rules;
  console.log(ruleSearch.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < ruleSearch.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, ruleSearch[i].selectorText, type)
    if (ruleSearch[i].selectorText == type) {
      var target = ruleSearch[i];
      console.log(target)
      break;
    }
  }
  for (var keys in attrs) {
    if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
      target.style[keys] = attrs[keys];
    }
  }
}


window.onload = function() {
  setStyleRule("body", {
    "background-color": "red"
  });
}
```

```css
body {}
```

Comment: What is target? I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML or stylesheets to make it a [mcve]

Comment: css file is always to be an external css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added console.logs that explains you the problem. You set the target inside an if that is never true. So set the target to nothing outside the loop and test if it is even found

[Test it here](https://plungjan.name/SO/teststyle/) - it cannot be tested at SO due to errors when loading my stylesheet into SO's iFrame (cross origin)

```
  var target;
  console.log(ruleSearch.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < ruleSearch.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, ruleSearch[i].selectorText, type)
    if (ruleSearch[i].selectorText == type) {
      target = ruleSearch[i];
      console.log("found", target)
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!target) {
    console.log(type, "not found")
    return
  }
```

Also I suggest you use addEventListener

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setStyleRule("body", {
    "background-color": "red"
  });
})
```

Comment: can you post the solution :(

Comment: Your code with my changes works. See https://plungjan.name/SO/teststyle/

Comment: I see now. It works since then. I just having a mistake on my localhost.